# gluLookAt вращается с запаздыванием

Tags: opengl, glut

У меня есть код на openGL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <QDebug>
using namespace std;

#define WIDTH 1024
#define HEIGHT 600

void display();
void reshape(int width, int height);
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void moveCamera();
void init();
void mkList();
//double z(const double &x, const double &y);
//void enableLight();
//void idle();

GLuint idList = 0;

double e_x = 0;
double e_y = 0;
double e_z = 0;
double r = 300;
double phi = 0;
double theta = 1.5;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(30, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Lab#2");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
//    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    init();
    mkList();
//    enableLight();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    moveCamera();
    glCallList(idList);

    glFinish();
}

void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
//    glOrtho(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, -width/2, width/2);
    gluPerspective(45, 2, 100, 2000);
//    glFrustum(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, 100, 500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
#define ESCAPE '\033'

    switch (key)
    {
    case ESCAPE:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 's':
        theta += 0.1;
        break;
    case 'w':
        theta -= 0.1;
        break;
    case 'a':
        phi += 0.1;
        break;
    case 'd':
        phi -= 0.1;
        break;
    case 'q':
        r-=5;
        break;
    case 'e':
        r+=5;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    e_x = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
    e_z = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
    e_y = r * cos(theta);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void moveCamera()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    int vec = ceil(theta / 3.1415);
    int y;
    if (vec%2)
        y = 1;
    else
        y = -1;
    gluLookAt(e_x, e_y, e_z, 0, 0, 0, 0, y, 0);
}

void init()
{
    e_x = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
    e_z = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
    e_y = r * cos(theta);
}

void mkList()
{
    int idInnerList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(idInnerList, GL_COMPILE);

    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-200, 0, 0);
    glutWireSphere(50, 10, 10);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(200, 0, 0);
    glutSolidCube(100);
    glPopMatrix();

    glEndList();

    idList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(idList, GL_COMPILE);
    glCallList(idInnerList);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 200);
    glCallList(idInnerList);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -200);
    glCallList(idInnerList);
    glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();
}
```

Посмотрим на функцию display()

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    moveCamera();
    glCallList(idList);

    glFinish();
}
```

В функции display есть функция moveCamera()

```
void moveCamera()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    int vec = ceil(theta / 3.1415);
    int y;
    if (vec%2)
        y = 1;
    else
        y = -1;
    gluLookAt(e_x, e_y, e_z, 0, 0, 0, 0, y, 0);
}
```

При вышеприведенном расположении функции moveCamera в функции display все отлично работает. Но стоит перенести функцию moveCamera в конец функции display(), вот так:

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glCallList(idList);

    moveCamera();
    glFinish();
}
```

Тогда вращение идет с опозданием на последнюю клавишу. То есть я нажимаю вправо-вправо-влево-влево
а камера вращается
вправо-вправо-вправо-влево

Я не понимаю, в чем дело. Кто может объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

При переносе функции moveCamera(); новые настройки камеры применятся только к следующему кадру. Другими словами glCallList(idList); будет использовать "предыдущие настройки камеры".

Вам стоит понимать как работает перемещение объектов и камеры в OpenGL. Эти функции меняют текущие матрицы (трансформации) объектов, которые будут использованы при следующем рендере. Если вы отрисовали объект в backbuffer или в frontbuffer, то изменения камеры после этого не изменят текущий отрисованный ранее кадр. Команда glFinish все навсего синхронизирует выполнения команд на видеокарте с CPU.

Comment: я так и ничего не понял. Почему это настройки будут применяться к следующему кадру а не текущему? gluLookAt это же тоже умножение матриц, аналогичное rotate, scale, translate. Почему умножение будет применяться к следующему?

Comment: Потому что для функции, где moveCamera(); в конце отрисовка уже произошла и настройка применится только к следующему вызову display().